# Keeping control of alarms and notifications

Tags: notifications, alarm

Often alarms and timers doesn't make a sound.  Other times unexpected sounds in the middle of the night.  Often they are "in the background" so I have to find the app making it before I can stop it.

So how can I have good control of upcoming alarms, notifications and how they will appear?  How can I be sure they are easy to stop?
(I assume this must be about interaction between OS and app, so I need some way to check if apps confirms to standards)

Pixel with latest Android, Wear OS (And Google/Chrome on Windows)

Comment: There must be a setting "Do Not Disturb". Switch that ON and set it to "Alarms only". That should forbid all apps from making sounds until you disable DND. This will prevent unexpected sounds in the middle of the night.

Comment: That's 1/3 o the problem - and only if "Alarms" are well defined.